Condition for Hermite series $\sum_n a_n H_n$ to be uniformly bounded?
Suppose we have a function
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n H_n(x), 
$$
where $H_n$ are the Hermite polynomials and $a = (a_n)$ is square summable.
I am wondering what conditions allow:

(i) the series above to converge pointwise, and
(ii) that $\|f\|_\infty := \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)|$ is finite.

I can see that under the condition that $a$ is square summable we have that the series converges in $L^2(\gamma)$ where $\gamma$ denotes the standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}$. However, I don't think this says anything about the pointwise convergence of the series above.
Secondly, I can see that if $a_n$ is eventually $0$, then $\|f\|_\infty < \infty$ if and only if $a_n = 0$ for all $n \geq 1$. This is because in this case we have $f = \sum_{n\leq N} a_n H_n(x)$ for some $N$ large enough and $|a_N| > 0$. Then, by inspection
$f(x) x^{-N} = a_N + o(1)$ as $x \to \infty$, which implies that $|f(x)| \to \infty$.
However, my reasoning above only applies for $a \in c_{00} \subset \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.
